# Ошибка связывания при использовании шаблона вида template<int i>

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Например, имеются файлы A.h:

```
template<int i> class A{ 
public:
int arrSz();
private:
int arr[i]{0};
};
```

файл A.cpp:

```
#include "1.h"

template<int i> int A<i>::arrSz() {
return sizeof(arr) / 4;
}
```

файл main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "1.h"

int main(){
A<5> a{};
std::cout << a.arrSz() << std::endl;
return 0;
}
```

данный код выдает ошибку на этапе связывания, почему?

Comment: определение шаблона  напишите тоже в заголовочном файле

Comment: Можно определение шаблона оставить в том же файле, но в конце хидера `A.h` нужно заинклюдить файл с определением. Само собой ваш файл с определением не должен компилироваться. Кстати у вас там почему-то `A.cpp` инклюдит `1.h` а не `A.h` - думаю это просто опечатка